# How to see current exception in VS Code Python Debugger in except clause

Tags: python, vscode-debugger

I am using VS Code to debug Python application.
If I have the following code

```py
try:
  do_something()
catch Exception:
  handle_exception()  # <--- program is here
```

Is there a way in VS Code to watch the exception catch even though I didn't assigned it to a variable?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to `import sys` in your code

Then when you launch your debug session add manually `sys.exc_info()` to watch in the Watch menu

It will display the exception in this menu then.

```
import sys

try :
    something = 1/0
except :
    print("Error: ")
```

[image: Debug]